# Can I apply for Schengen visa 4 months before travel

Tags: usa, schengen, france, indian-citizens

I am indian citizen on H1b visa in US. I am planning to visit France in Oct 2014. Can I apply for Schengen visa now about 3/4 months in advance. Are there any restrictions that on early you can apply for Schengen visa.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot, you can only apply 90 days prior to the start of the visit. This is clearly mentioned on several Schengen Countries' embassies.

For instance, on the [German Embassy (VFS Global) for the UK](http://www.vfsglobal.com/GERMANY/UK/faq.html)

> Q.7   How early can I apply? Ans  Applicants are free to apply up to 90
>   days prior to their date of travel. The Embassy recommends that you
>   apply at least 3 weeks prior to your date of travel to accommodate any
>   unforeseen processing delays.