# Is there a rule stating that the Schengen visa cannot be applied more than 3 months in advance?

Tags: visas, schengen, regulations

Is there such a general rule that no tourist Schengen visa application can be submitted earlier than 3 months before the first day of the planned entry?

EDIT. The similar question in [Can I apply for Schengen visa 4 months before travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-4-months-before-travel) is almost 3 years old by now, and the only reference link there is broken. As such regulations change frequently, old answers may get quickly inaccurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply for Schengen visa 4 months before travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/can-i-apply-for-schengen-visa-4-months-before-travel)

Comment: @Dorothy A 3 yrs old duplicate may be outdated, see the edit.

Comment: The referenced duplicate has a broken link and does not cite the appropriate  EU regulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 3 month maximum lead time for a Schengen application is statutory. The statement occurs in the [Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32009R0810), but it is more accessible in the summary page at [EUR-Lex](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=URISERV%3Ajl0028)

> A visa application may be lodged by the applicant or an accredited
>   commercial intermediary **at the earliest 3 months** before the intended
>   visit. When lodging an application, the applicant must appear in
>   person, unless this requirement has been waived. When lodging an
>   application, the following must be presented:

(emphasis mine)

Note: it does not matter if the 'three-month forward computed date' falls on a weekend or holiday.

Comment: Does it apply to all EU countries, not only Schengen? I know Ireland allows to file earlier applications than 3 months, so I am confused.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev The ROI is not a Schengen member. The question is scoped to Schengen regulations.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, the document confusingly mentions "EU country" but upon closer inspection there is indeed a reference to Schengen.

Comment: Article 9 is not particularly inaccessible: "Applications shall be lodged no more than three months before the start of the intended visit."